# Where python prometheus_client stores the data?

Tags: python, django, prometheus

Just a quick question here as I am quiet lazy to go through the code.. :) Where does python [prometheus_client](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python) stores all the data it captures? Is it stored in memory of current thread? If not then where?

I would like to use it with my django project in production, but my django app is seriously multi-threaded... How it will all play together?

I am planing to use [django-prometheus](https://github.com/korfuri/django-prometheus/blob/master/django_prometheus/exports.py) for that.

Answer (score 3):

It's all kept in memory, protected by a mutex. For a multi-threaded application it'll all Just Work.

Comment: Hmmm... Doesn't make to much sense to me... Mutex is depreciated in python 3... How it is doing shared data storage by using mutex? As per my knowleadge mutex is used to lock threads but not store some common data..?

What if i start multiple python apps running in the same python environment? Starting and restarting these apps at different times? How it will then handle the data from different apps? What if I have multiple instances of the same app running at the same time in the same environment?

Thank you youy in advance for your toughs!

Comment: Mutexes are not deprecated in Python 3, they're a core concurrency concept. Use use a mutex to lock access to the shared data. What do you mean by "same environment"? Same process?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/mutex.html says: "Deprecated since version 2.6: The mutex module has been removed in Python 3."

Same python environment - same python virtualenvironment for example.

Comment: That's the `mutex` module, we've always used the one in `thread`. If you're using the same virtual env then that's not relevant, that's the same as saying you use the same machine. As long as you've a port per app you're good.